# RegEx SQL Select not matched

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
(?i)(sql.*[\s\S]select.*[\s\S]from[\s\S]*?\;)
```

This one is matched

```
SQL SELECT Distinct Field1,Field2
FROM Table1
;
```

But this one is not matched

```
SQL SELECT Distinct 
     Field,
     Field2
FROM Table1
;
```

And this one also not:

```
SQL 
SELECT Field,Field2
FROM Table1;
```

Why does this happen?

I changed my regex to

```
(?im)^sql[\s\S]*?^;$
```

and now the first and the second one are matched, but not the third one.

https://regex101.com/r/qLUbBh/3

Answer (score 0):

```
(?im)^sql[\s\S]*?;$
```

This works.